# UPDATE with multiple values and CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql-update, concatenation

I am trying to add multiple values into database field with CONCAT.

Two tables are involved:

products_description

```
+-----+------------+--------------------+
| id  |products_id | products_keywords  | 
+-----+------------+--------------------+-
| 123 | 1          |  something         | 
| 124 | 2          |  somethingelse     | 
+-----+------------+--------------------+-
```

products_spare

```
+-----+------------+--------------------+
| id  |spare_id    | products_name      | 
+-----+------------+--------------------+-
| 222 | 2          |  something to add  | 
| 223 | 2          |  something to add 2| 
+-----+------------+--------------------+-
```

My Update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE products_description pd
LEFT JOIN products_spare ps
ON pd.products_id = ps.spare_id
SET pd.products_keywords = CONCAT(pd.products_keywords," ",ps.products_name)
```

So "something to add" and "something to add 2" should both be going into the second row of table products_description in the products_keywords field. But only one does. I guess I am doing something stupidly wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go down this road?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: This violates 3NF - the foundation of an RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-know problem when an `UPDATE ... JOIN ...` has multiple matching rows; typically, only one update happens.

You can work around this by pre-aggregating the product names of each spare in a subquery using `group_concat()`, and then join.

```
UPDATE products_description pd
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT spare_id, GROUP_CONCAT(products_name separator ' ') products_names
    FROM products_spare 
    GROUP BY spare_id
) ps ON pd.products_id = ps.spare_id
SET pd.products_keywords = CONCAT(pd.products_keywords, ' ', ps.products_names)
```

Side notes:

- you probably want an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` (when there is no matching record, there is nothing to update)
- use single quotes for strings instead of double quotes: this is the SQL standard

Comment: You made my day. Thanks a lot. And I was almost there becuase I started playing around with the subquery. What if now I have duplicate strings in my products_keywords? Is there a way to avoid that upfront or do I have to solve this via PHP? When I say duplicates I mean "something to add" would be a duplicate. What If I only want "something to add" added once + "2"?

Comment: @fetz_braun: `group_concat()` supports distinct, so: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_name SEPARATOR ' ')`.

Comment: ok yes thanks. I thought so. But unfortunatly this does not help if the values are like in my example. I will nevertheless have "something to add something to add 2" in my field. Because DISTINCT will only check if the entries are identical. I will try to find a php function to "clean" it.